# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setParams')] salesforce Aura

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura

[image: error]

**The exception or the component error we are looking at is not able to find OrderNumber**

**PrescriptiveResolutionTool.cmp**

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" controller="nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl">

    <aura:attribute name="orderNumber" type="String" default="0"/> 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="orderPrescPriceLineItemList" type="List" Description="nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl.PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass"/>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="medium" variant="brand"/>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.orderPrescPriceLineItemList.length > 0}">
    <article class="slds-card">
                    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                <!-- code to display card header -->
                <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">                    
                    <div class="slds-media__figure">
                        <span class="slds-icon_container">
                            <lightning:icon style="background-color: rgba(32,178,170,1);" iconName="custom:custom29" size="small"/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Prescriptive Order Line Items">
                                <span>
                                    Prescriptive Resolution Items   
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                    </div> 
                </header>                
            </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout" style="padding-top:0.1rem" role="grid" id="summaryTable">
                    <!-- CODE TO DISPLAY THE TABLE HEADER STARTS HERE -->
                    <thead class="slds-table_bordered">
                        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">                                                                    
                            <th scope="col">                        
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Order Line Items">Order Line Items </p>                                                                                                    
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">                        
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Product Description">Product Description</p>                                                                            
                            </th>               
                            <th scope="col">                        
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Sales Price">Sales Price Per Item</p>                                                        
                            </th>                
                            <th scope="col">                        
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Order Status">Order Status</p>                                                        
                            </th>                
                            <th scope="col">                        
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="C/A Amount">C/A Amount Per Item</p>                                                        
                            </th>            
                            <th scope="col">                        
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="CDL Amount">CDL Amount Per Item</p>                                                        
                            </th>            
                            <th scope="col">                        
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Maximum Resolution Amount">Maximum Resolution Amount Per Item</p>                                                        
                            </th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.orderPrescPriceLineItemList}" var="record">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                    {!record.OrderLineItems }
                                </td>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                    {!record.ProductDescription}
                                </td>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                    {!record.SalesPrice}
                                </td>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                    {!record.OrderStatus}
                                </td>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                    {!record.CAAmount}
                                </td>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                    {!record.CDLAmount}
                                </td>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                    {!record.MaximumResolutionAmount}
                                </td>                                
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    </article>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div align="center">
                    <hr></hr>
                    No Records Found
                </div>
            </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**nfm_PrescriptiveResolutionToolHelper.js**

```javascript
({
    getPrescriptivePriceLineItemsInfo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var orderNumber = component.get("v.orderNumber");
        console.log('OrderId to Apex call' + orderNumber);
        var action = component.get('c.getOrderPrescriptivePriceLineItems');
        action.setParams({
            orderId: component.get("v.orderNumber")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 
            component.set('v.isLoading',false);
            var state = response.getState();
            var dataRetrieved = response.getReturnValue();            
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataRetrieved)));
                //console.log('Response of Prescriptive Resolution for an OrderNumber--' + dataRetrieved);
                component.set('v.orderPrescPriceLineItemList', dataRetrieved);

            }else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            } 
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**nfm_PrescriptiveResolutionToolController.js**

```javascript
({
     doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var orderId = component.get("v.orderNumber");
        var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");  
        if(myPageRef!=null){
            orderId = myPageRef && myPageRef.state ? myPageRef.state.c__orderNumber :  component.get('v.recordId');
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myPageRef.state)));
            console.log(orderId);
        }else{
            orderId = component.get('v.recordId');
        }

        if(orderId!=undefined && orderId!=null){
            component.set('v.orderNumber',orderId);
            window.setTimeout(
                $A.getCallback(function() {
                    helper.getPrescriptivePriceLineItemsInfo(component, event, helper);
                }),3000
            );
        }
    }
})
```

**APEX CLASS**

```apex
public class nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass> getOrderPrescriptivePriceLineItems(String orderId) {
        System.debug('OrderNumber Apex:' + orderId);
        List<ResolutionItems__x> resolutionItemList = nfm_ExternalResolutionItemRequest.getByOrderNumber(orderId);
        List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass> lineItemWrapperList = new List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass>();
        For(ResolutionItems__x objOrderLineItems : resolutionItemList){
            lineItemWrapperList.add(createLineItemWrapperObject(objOrderLineItems));
        }
        UserActivityController.createRecord('Prescriptive Tool', 'Order', orderId);
        return lineItemWrapperList;
    }
      
    private static PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass createLineItemWrapperObject(ResolutionItems__x objOrderLineItems){
        PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass objOrderLineItemWrapper = new PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass();
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.OrderLineItems = objOrderLineItems.OrderLineItemNumber__c;
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.ProductDescription = objOrderLineItems.ProductDescription__c;
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.SalesPrice = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.SalesPrice__c);
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.OrderStatus = objOrderLineItems.OrderStatus__c;
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.CAAmount = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.CreditAdjustmentAmount__c);
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.CDLAmount = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.CDLAmount__c);
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.MaximumResolutionAmount = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.MaximumResolutionAmount__c);
        
        return objOrderLineItemWrapper;
    }
    
    public class PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass{
        @AuraEnabled public String OrderLineItems{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String ProductDescription{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String SalesPrice {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String OrderStatus {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String CAAmount {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String CDLAmount {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String MaximumResolutionAmount {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: It's well worth considering eyescream's answer to your crossposted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73644656/uncaught-error-in-a-getcallback-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading). Yes, it can't find the OrderNumber, but this is very unlikely the origin of the error and very likely follows from the same problem that causes the failed "setParams": `component` does not behave when called from the callback. From what I can tell eyescream demonstrated that your code works on a record page - maybe it doesn't in the Lightning console app, where you seem to use it?

Comment: @parker_1947, https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IHXLQA4  Does this answer your question?